# Run a job in management studio when another two jobs have been successful?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a problem related to a job that has dependencies on two other jobs. My question is whether there is any possibility to run a job in SQL Server Management Studio only when another two jobs stored on my server have been successful.

Thanks in advance!

I can´t find anything in the internet.

Comment: SSMS doesn't run jobs? That's SQL server agent. And pretty sure you can setup steps to run when other steps pass.

Comment: True, I was talking about SQL Server Agent, sorry. The fact is that I have two separate jobs that are executed in parallel, and I need to know how to run another job which must start once those two are successful (these two have different run times).

Comment: create some state table that holds a flag containing values 0, 1, 2. each job is only run when the flag is set to correct value, and the final job sets the flag back to 0

Comment: When you say "have been successful" how far back? The most recent run? Any run ever, or the last week, what? Please be clear.

Comment: My client doesn't want to have a stable state with flags. @Charlieface, yes, it must be the most recent run that is successful, and it runs every day every 4 hours.

Comment: Fine, you can check out msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity etc to see how the jobs have ran recently, and then make decisions based on that

Comment: you could also enable/disable the next job schedules and other fancy stuff like that, but it'll probably lead to more problems than solutions

Answer (score 2):

Based off an answer from https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/279117/query-to-view-failure-detail-for-a-given-sql-agent-job-step, by "Scott Hodgin - retired", there is a way to check success or failures of a job by querying msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory.

The documentation for msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysjobhistory-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16, and indicates that the `[run_status]` is an integer column and indicates success when it equals 1.

The job name is stored in msdb.dbo.sysjobs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysjobs-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), which you should be able to filter for.

You would have to run a query (probably a stored procedure) looking at those values every 4 hours like you requested in comments; and if both conditions are true then you perform your desired actions.  My attempt at modifying that query for 2 successful job events is below:

```
--Run a SQL Agent job every 4 hours according to OP
DECLARE @jobname1 sysname = 'thejobname1'
       ,@jobname2 sysname = 'thejobname2'

IF (
SELECT TOP 1 jh.run_status
  FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS j
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps AS js
   ON js.job_id = j.job_id
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory AS jh
   ON jh.job_id = j.job_id AND jh.step_id = js.step_id
 WHERE j.name = @jobname1
ORDER BY jh.run_date DESC, jh.run_time DESC
) = 1

AND

(
SELECT TOP 1 jh.run_status
  FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS j
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps AS js
   ON js.job_id = j.job_id
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory AS jh
   ON jh.job_id = j.job_id AND jh.step_id = js.step_id
 WHERE j.name = @jobname2
ORDER BY jh.run_date DESC, jh.run_time DESC
) = 1

BEGIN
 SELECT 'success' AS [message]
END
```